# c struct pointers and scope confusion

Tags: c

I have a program made of 3 files.

- main.c  contains the external variables for the stack and contains the code to parse input and pass the input to the functions in stack.c
- stack.c    //contains the functions to execute the operations on the stack push/pull etc
- stack.h    //contains the function prototypes

The program currently uses a global integer array as a stack.

Im now trying to convert the program to use a linked list for the stack instead of the integer array.

My issue is I don’t know where I should declare the struct and where I should declare the struct members. Should i put them in the main.c outside the main function, in the stack.h header file ?

my struct declaration

```
struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *first = NULL;
struct node *new_node = NULL;


new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: the struct definition and the declarations of the pointers **can** be kept global. `new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` **must** be inside a function (eg main()), since it generates "code", not "data".

Comment: I'm not sure why you need two pointers for a linked list stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stack.c`

```
#include "stack.h"
struct node *first = NULL;
struct node *new_node = NULL;
```

In `stack.h`

```
struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};

extern struct node *first;
extern struct node *new_node;
```

In `main.c`

```
#include "stack.h"
//inside main
//new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //don't forgot to free it
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your structure definition and extern variable declaration in header file and include your header file in other `.c` files. [don't forget to add header guards [(include guard)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)].

Then, create variables of the structure type in your `main.c` [and use in `stack.c` file also]. That's the common analogy.

#### Example

```
//stack.h
struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
};

extern struct node *g_first_node;
extern struct node *g_new_node;
```

then, in `main.c`

```
#include "stack.h"
struct node *g_first_node= NULL;
struct node *g_new_node= NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Excluding any debate on global variables, I see two options:

1) Define your structure only in stack.c, and just declare it in stack.h:

```
/*stack.h*/
struct node;

extern struct node *g_first_node = NULL;
extern struct node *g_new_node = NULL;
```

2) Put the structure definition in stack.h, so all the code referncing it can use it.